# How to convert Swiper.js into ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, swiper.js

I use babel to convert it but the swiper is not working and it shows this error in console.

[image]

I go to the line where this error happen and add `console.log()`.

```
      if (params.el && $(params.el).length > 1) {
        var swipers = [];
        console.log($(params.el))
        $(params.el).each(function (containerEl) {
          var newParams = extend({}, params, {
            el: containerEl
          });
          swipers.push(new Swiper(newParams));
        });
        return swipers;
      } // Swiper Instance
```

There's no problem getting these elements but somehow `$(...).each` just doesn't work.

[image]

What can i do to fix this?

Or is there something wrong when converting?

My `.babel` is simple, as below

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

I use `gulp-babel` to convert it.
In `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^8.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  },
```

And in `gulpfile.js`:

```
function to_es5() {
  gulp
    .src("./src/js/*.js")
    .pipe(
      babel({
        presets: ["es2015"],      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./src/js-es5/"))
 }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with babel or ES5. It means that you need to install jQuery or whatever `$` that library is depending on.

Comment: Note that swiper itself does not depend on jQuery at all.

Comment: `$(params.el).length` isn't throwing an error. So, something specific to do with `.each`. Is that being used correctly?

Comment: A quick look at swiper.js and it uses [Dom7](https://framework7.io/docs/dom7.html) which has *"a jquery-compatible API"* - so whatever you've used to "convert" it has assumed you have jquery (given the `$(..)` syntax) and converted it incorrectly (or not converted it at all at that point?)  ... *probably*.

Comment: What is `$(params.el)`? If it was a jQuery object then it should have an `each` function. This doesn't seem to be related to ES5 though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering!
jQuery has been installed already, so when i added ```console.log(params.el)``` it did get these elements as the 2nd image shows.
Also, it worked fine before I converted it into ES5, that why I guessed something went when convertting.

Comment: Do you have the original code from before converting to es5? I wouldn't expect babel to generate broken JavaScript.

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-test-dtz29w)
I made a demonstration, please take a look of you don't mind.
The ```swiper-es6.js``` is from [link](https://unpkg.com/swiper@8.0.6/swiper-bundle.js)

Comment: Can you show us what you did to convert swiper to es5?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I edited the post to show more detail due to characters limit.
(i use it to convert my other js file in this project and it works)